# Integrating Zxing Barcode Scanner With My Android App - Custom Action Name Issue

Tags: android, android-activity, barcode-scanner, zxing, android-intent

So I have successfully integrated Zxing into my application. However I want to make the entry Action name different so that users don't have to select between the barcode scanner app and my app for scanning if they have Zxing's apk installed. I figured I could do this by changing`com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN` to something else in my calling intent and my Android manifest.

It seems to work, except I am not getting a result from CaptureActivity. Instead, I am just getting results for the product in the scanner as if the app was not running via intent. I'm not sure if anyone has experienced this issue before. Any help is appreciated, and I can post more info if necessary.

Comment: If you could post some code samples that would help

Comment: I found the answer to this. I started thinking, and realized that the CaptureActivity would need to know that the action name was being called in order to determine the type of result. I didn't find it anywhere in the activity, so I did a project wide search of the original action name, and found Intents.java, which is a class of static intent action names to be used. I changed the scan action name in this file as well, and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this. I started thinking, and realized that the CaptureActivity would need to know that the action name was being called in order to determine the type of result. I didn't find it anywhere in the activity, so I did a project wide search of the original action name, and found Intents.java, which is a class of static intent action names to be used. I changed the scan action name in this file as well, and it works now.